# Cordova deploy app on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have a app that runs in the iOS-simulator. The app is compiled with cordova 3.4. After that, I can run the app via shell by calling "cordova run iOS" as well as open the project in xCode and press the play button. Both works.

I attempted to put the app on my iOS-device (iPhone-5s, iPad-Retina). But that does work neither with console nor with xCode.

When I try to run the app on the console by "start iOS" the console freezes before the app is installed on the device. I don't get any error logs. It tried that a few times, and sometimes the app is installed, but the console freezes.

Trying to run the app with xCode I get those errors and issues:

[image]
[image]

I have the current versions of iOS, xCode and MacOS as well as a developer ID, that is requested by the cordova-console when I try to start the app on a real device. The device was set to a working-group of my apple-developer account, too. That shouldn't cause the problems.

The build-location was set to unique and xcode-default. That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try removing the platform and adding it back again (`cordova platform rm ios` / `cordova platform add ios`). Not sure if it will make a difference, but I've had occasions where this clears up odd errors like this.

Comment: Unfortunately not working.

Comment: Have you validated your project settings? Does Xcode suggest any changes?

Comment: No, Xcode doesn't suggest any changes. How do I validate my project settings?
I guess it could be a problem that I let Xcode open an already compiled project by cordova. If I get my test-device back, I try to only prepare my project and let Xcode take care of the compilation process.